# munmap_chunk: invalid pointer in a C program using function in a dynamic library generated by rust

Tags: c, rust, ffi

I have a function in `Rust`. It receive a `*const c_char` and transfer it into a string.

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn listen(addr: *const c_char) {
    unsafe {
        let addr_str = {
            let cstr = CStr::from_ptr(addr);
            let bytes = cstr.to_bytes();
            String::from_raw_parts(bytes.as_ptr() as *mut u8, bytes.len(), bytes.len())
        };
    }
}
```

And in C program, I get the address from the command line.

```
#include "xxx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// input: address
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Usage %s <listen_addr>\n", argv[0]);
    return -1;
  }

  const char *addr = argv[1];

  listen(addr);

  return 0;

}
```

It will throw the error `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer`.
However, if I choose to store the address on the heap, the program wouldn't throw the error.

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Usage %s <listen_addr>\n", argv[0]);
    return -1;
  }

  const char *addr = argv[1];

  int addr_len = strlen(addr) + 1;

  char *addr_buffer = (char *)malloc(addr_len);
  strcpy(addr_buffer, addr);

  listen(addr_buffer);

  return 0;

}
```

Why does it not work if you put the address on the stack but it works if you put it on the heap?

Comment: Perhaps don't use `from_raw_parts`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does it not work if you put the address on the stack but it works if you put it on the heap?

Because this:

> ```rust
> String::from_raw_parts(bytes.as_ptr() as *mut u8, bytes.len(), bytes.len())
> ```

Is completely unsound, in both cases:

1. `String` is an owned type, when it goes out of scope its contents get deallocated, but in the first case since it was almost certainly not directly allocated (only implicitly as part of the stack -- in most cases though that's not actually guaranteed) the allocator errors as you ask it to free what is, as far as its concerned, not a valid pointer (and that's a best case scenario).
2. Even if you move the string to "the heap" it's still unsound, because there's no guarantee your C and Rust runtimes use the same allocator, you can't free allocations from one allocator with an other.

Both versions are also unsound because Rust requires a `String`'s buffer be UTF8, but there is no validation whatsoever of that.

The entire thing is absolutely baffling given there is a [`CStr::to_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html#method.to_str) method which literally does all the right things correctly (hence it not even being unsafe).

Comment: Thanks! I just learn some examples from network and don't know the `to_str` function.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of [`from_raw_parts()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_raw_parts) tells us

> The memory at buf needs to have been previously allocated by the same allocator the standard library uses, with a required alignment of exactly 1.

and

> The ownership of buf is effectively transferred to the String which may then deallocate, reallocate or change the contents of memory pointed to by the pointer at will.

Here you create a `String` this way, but as soon as it is dropped it tries to deallocate the memory region.
In your first attempt, you directly refer to `argv[]` which is on the stack, the deallocation will certainly fail.
Maybe, in your second attempt, the allocation means is (by chance) compatible with what is expected by Rust, but nothing guaranties that.

Comment: Thank you! It seems like the function written in `Rust` I need to refine.